# Multiple Solr Instances - Second Solr Locked on Startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I've been trying to figure out a workflow where my Minitest suite will launch a second Solr instance for feature tests even if the development instance is running. However, I'm running into issues just getting the servers to start (i.e. when I start them outside of testing).

To start my servers I'm using:

```
RAILS_ENV=development bin/rake sunspot:solr:start
RAILS_ENV=test bin/rake sunspot:solr:start
```

However, whichever server starts *second* becomes locked. Any attempt to access the server in tests or just in development yields this error:

```
RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
Error:     {msg=SolrCore 'test& 'is not available due to init failure: Index locked for write for core 'test'. Solr now longer supports forceful unlocking via 'unlockOnStartup'. Please verify locks manually!,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore 'test' is not available due to init failure: Index locked for write for core 'test'. Solr now longer supports forceful unlocking via 'unlockOnStartup'. Please verify locks manually!
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:974)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:250)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:417)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:214)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)

URI: http://localhost:8981/solr/test/update?wt=ruby
Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}
Request Data: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><add/>"
```

I've searched around for issues related to locking but I can't find any where the problem is having two servers running. My setup is:

```
Rails (5.0.0.1)
sunspot (2.2.5)
sunspot_rails (2.2.5)
sunspot_solr (2.2.5)
ruby 2.3.1p112
```

My `sunspot.yml` is:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/production

development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/development

test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8981
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

And finally, `solr.xml`

```
<solr>

  <solrcloud>

    <str name="host">${host:}</str>
    <int name="hostPort">${jetty.port:8983}</int>
    <str name="hostContext">${hostContext:solr}</str>

    <bool name="genericCoreNodeNames">${genericCoreNodeNames:true}</bool>

    <int name="zkClientTimeout">${zkClientTimeout:30000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateSoTimeout">${distribUpdateSoTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="distribUpdateConnTimeout">${distribUpdateConnTimeout:60000}</int>

  </solrcloud>

  <shardHandlerFactory name="shardHandlerFactory" class="HttpShardHandlerFactory">
    <int name="socketTimeout">${socketTimeout:600000}</int>
    <int name="connTimeout">${connTimeout:60000}</int>
  </shardHandlerFactory>

</solr>
```

Thank you so much in advance!